# Ecto.Changeset related model error on update

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ecto is giving me an error on updating a has_one association:

Model in question:

```
defmodule Something.Parent do
  has_one :thing, Something.thing

  @required_fields ~w(field1 field2 thing)
end
```

Controller update action

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "parent" => parent_params}) do                            
   parent = Repo.get!(Parent, id) |> Repo.preload(:thing)

   changeset = Parent.changeset(parent, parent_params)                                                        

   case Repo.update(changeset) do
     {:ok, _parent} ->                                                                            
       conn                                                                                     
       |> put_flash(:info, "Parent updated successfully")                                         
       |> redirect(to: parent_path(conn, :index))                                                                             
     {:error, changeset} ->
       render(conn, "edit.html", parent: parent, changeset: changeset) 
   end                                                               
 end
```

Params

parent = %{"some_number" => "902", "thing" => %{"somethingfield" => "blah", "parent_id" => "8"}

Error

```
you are attempting to change relation :thing of
Whatever.Parent, but there is missing data.

By default, if the parent model contains N children, at least the same
N children must be given on update. In other words, it is not possible
to orphan embed nor associated records, attempting to do so results
in this error message.

It is possible to change this behaviour by setting :on_replace when
defining the relation. See `Ecto.Changeset`'s section on related models
for more info.
```

Based on the docs it looks like the changeset function on the parent model is seeing the 'Thing' being orphaned from the parent - but I can't see why?

The new/create actions work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a `thing` associated to the parent you are changing.

As the error message specifies, you can change this with the `on_replace` option of [has_one/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_one/3)

> :on_replace - The action taken on associations when the model is replaced when casting or manipulating parent changeset. May be :raise (default), :mark_as_invalid, :nilify, or :delete. See Ecto.Changeset‘s section on related models for more info.

[Ecto.Changeset docs](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html).

Comment: If I wanted changes to propagate would I do :delete to delete the previous thing and replace it with the new thing?

Comment: @RichardHolland There are several options - I have added a link to more detailed documentation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  :delete gets what I desire

Comment: @RichardHolland the issue in your case may simply be that you are not passing the ID. So we don't know if you are trying to keep the same reference or create a new one.

Comment: @JoséValim Any idea why the ID wouldn't be included in the params?  the on_replace code fixes it but if the ID is the issue I would rather fix it there.

Comment: I am not sure. If you are using inputs_for, like mentioned here http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/, it was supposed to be included automatically.

Comment: I found out this is a bug in Ecto. It is fixed in the v1.0 branch. We will push Ecto v1.0.5 soon. :D Thanks for "reporting"!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Ecto.  Fixed on master with this commit.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/commit/6c1c04304ebecf5ccae4a49008deab814e034d2b